# Optimize YUY2 to I420 conversion

Tags: c++, video, optimization

I am writing a video conference application with x264 as encoder. I receive YUY2 raw frames from the webcam and then convert them into I420, as requested by x264. The problem is - I wrote conversion algoritm by myself and it is not so fast (up 20% of the whole CPU time, data provided by profiler). How can I make it faster? Here is my code:

```
int YUY2ToI420(BYTE *in, BYTE *out){

    long pixels = _width * _height;
    long macropixels = pixels / 2; // macropixel count
    // new size will be w * h * 3/2 -> 12 bits per pixel 4:2:0

    long mpx_per_row = info.biWidth / 2;

    // for each macropixel
    for (int i = 0, ci = 0; i < macropixels; i++){ // ci is chroma index
        // get macropixel address, order is Y0 U0 Y1 V0
        BYTE *mpAddress = in + i * 4;

        // copy luma data
        out[i * 2] = mpAddress[0];
        out[i * 2 + 1] = mpAddress[2];

        // copy chroma data - we skip odd rows because of 4:2:0 sampling
        long row_number = i / mpx_per_row;
        if (row_number % 2 == 0) {
            out[pixels + ci] = mpAddress[1]; // shift by Y vector
            out[pixels + pixels / 4 + ci] = mpAddress[3]; // shift by Y and U vector
            ci++;
        }
    }

    return pixels * 12 / 8; // I420
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend you use sws_scale from the ffmpeg project. It has optimized functions for most CPU and color formats. You could also use opencv I believe, but I have no first hand experience with it.